# Free Newsletter component for joomla 1.5.20

Tags: joomla, components

I need a simple and flexible component for free to install in my website. I search a lot and found some components like cc newsletter, letter man etc...

But i can't to able download.

Is there any component which is available to send newsletter for the subscribed users. Kindly help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to download. There are quite a few newsletter components available, I've used AcyMailer and it's pretty good.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter